# Implement Multhithreading in for loop in c# without Parallel.For()

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I am relatively new to Multithreading.I have written a for loop for printing values from 0 to a int number specified by the user.I now want to parallelise it in such a way that each thread prints 5 numbers.It is working when I use Parallel.For().But I can't seem to do it manually.Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static int no = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        no = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Parallel.For(0, no, i =>
        //Console.WriteLine(i)
        //);
        //Console.ReadLine();
        int start = 0, end = 5, i = 0;
        int not = no / 5;

        if (no <= 5)
        {
            func(start, no);
        }

        else
        {
            int index = i;
            Thread[] t = new Thread[not + 1];

            while (index < not + 1)
            {
                if (end - start >= 5 && end <= no)
                    t[index] = new Thread(() => func(start, end));

                else
                    t[index] = new Thread(() => func(start, no));

                start = end;
                end = end + 5;

                i++;
                t[index].Start();

            }
          Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static public void func(int start, int end)
    {

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i+",");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Suppose the user input value is 21.Then it produces the following output

```
15,16,17,15,16,17,18,19,18,19,25,26,27,28,29,25,26,27,28,29
```

However after using thread.join() just after t[index].start(),The following output is produced.

```
5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
```

I can't seem to understand what is going on and I can't debug this code as there are many threads running simultaneously.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a lambda expression like `() => func(start, end)` is bound to the variables start and end and will on execution use the value the variables happen to have at this time, not the values they had when creating the thread.

You can avoid this by first assigning the current values to variables defined within the loop and useing these in your lambdas, e.g.

```
if (end - start >= 5 && end <= no)
{
    var localStart = start;
    var localEnd = end;
    t[index] = new Thread(() => func(localStart, localEnd));
}
else
{
    var localStart = start;
    var localEnd = no;
    t[index] = new Thread(() => func(localStart, localEnd));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.But I'm afraid it didn't work out for me!

Comment: What output is produced now and what is still wrong with it?

Comment: After joining it is producing 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,

Comment: And what is wrong with this output? Or is this the expected output and you get some other numbers? Note that the output will produce the output in more or less random order as the 4 threads are doing their work independently.

Comment: I think it should start printing from 1 and go till 21 as the entered limit is 21 but it starts from 5 and goes till 24

Comment: It should get from 0 to 19 (but not necessarily in this order) and that's what I get after applying the change. I will edit my answer to make it clearer what I meant.

Comment: Ok Klaus.Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you! Please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it can help other people checking this question, too.